# Request.LogonUserIdentity and WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()

Tags: authentication, iis, identity

```
 Response.Write("Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name:" +Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name);
 Response.Write("<br/>");            
 Response.Write("WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name:" + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
 Response.Write("<br/>");
```

as above, if I use anonymous credential, it will be:

`Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name`**:NT AUTHORITY\IUSR**

`WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`**:IIS APPPOOL\TestSite**

But after impersonator, `LoginUserIdentity` will be the same

`Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name`**:NT AUTHORITY\IUSR**

`WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`**:impersonator identity**

**MSDN** said that

> The LogonUserIdentity property exposes the properties and methods of
>   the WindowsIdentity object for the currently connected user to
>   Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS).

Why `loginUserIdentity` is always the identity anonymous used??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstand authentication and impersonation,

```
Property Value

Type: System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity
A WindowsIdentity object for the current Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS) authentication settings.
```

Whether you enable impersonation or not, the logon user remains the same, so Request.LogonUserIdentity should remain the same, which obviously is correct and meet expectation.

The change of WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent is also expected, as that's just caused by impersonation.

Reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.logonuseridentity.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998351.aspx